# jQuery Slider UI - Enhancements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I was trying out jQuery Slider and used an example to play around.

**EDIT:**
I would like to have the slider show the values, like a ruler, to increase usability. As it is now, I am finding it difficult to pass the usability testing. People complain that they want to know what value they are picking before they start sliding.

Any ideas how I can achieve this ? As far as I searched, I could not find out about whether this feature already exists or about how to do this.

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="http://jqueryui.com/latest/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.slider.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #slider { margin: 10px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#slider").slider({           
            value: 50,
            min: 0,
            max: 99,
            step: 1,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val('$' + ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#amount").val('$' + $("#slider").slider("value"));
    });
</script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
<div id="slider"></div>
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

I found an example of a custom JQuery UI Slider that displays hash markings.

[jQuery UI Slider from a Select Element](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support//)

This should give you a good starting point. Let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

I've been keeping the input in synch with the slider like so

```
<div id='support_slider' class='slider' alt='" + pct + "'></div>
<input id='support_input' class='input' alt='" + pct + "' value='" + pct + "' size='1'/>

$("#support_slider").slider({
    //animate: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    value: pct,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
            set_sliders_and_input($(this), $(this).next(), $(this).next().attr("value"), ui.value);
    }
});

$("#support_input").keyup(function(event) {
    set_sliders_and_input($(this).prev(), $(this), $(this).attr("alt"), $(this).attr("value"));
});

function set_sliders_and_input(slider, input, oldv, newv) {
    if ( newv < 0 || newv > 100 ) return false;
    var diff = oldv - newv;
    input.attr("value", newv).attr("alt", newv);
    slider.slider('option', 'value', newv);
    GM_setValue('support_pct', newv);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help, he shows the values alongside the handle. pretty neat!:

http://www.keepthewebweird.com/creating-a-nice-slider-with-jquery-ui/

Watch the tutorial!! the demo is a bit off for some reason.